# PHP MySQL Multi User Login on Single UserID e.g. Corporate account with five usernames all accessing the same data

Tags: php, mysql

This relates to the login form only.  Users details in database are as follows

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `UserID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `Username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
    `Password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
    `EmailAddress` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `Pass1` VARCHAR(32) ,
    `User1` VARCHAR(65) ,
    `Pass2` VARCHAR(32) ,
    `User2` VARCHAR(65) ,
    `Pass3` VARCHAR(32) ,
    `User3` VARCHAR(65) ,
    `Pass4` VARCHAR(32) ,
    `User4` VARCHAR(65) ,
    `Pass5` VARCHAR(32) ,
    `User5` VARCHAR(65) 
);
```

I don't want the requirement for a corporate account to have to create five users etc. but that they can choose hence not utilizing NOT NULL.

I want all five users logged into a corporate account to have the same access as 1 user by checking their individual password and username off of each other.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
    {
?>
<h1>Member Area</h1>
<p>Thanks for logging in! You are <code><?=$_SESSION['Username']?></code> and your email address is <code><?=$_SESSION['EmailAddress']?></code>.</p>
<a href="logout.php">Logout<a>
<?php
    }
    elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
        if (($username) === false) {
            $user_cond = "user1='$username'";
            }
        else {
        $user_cond = "username='$username'";
        }
        $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT `UserID`,`Username`,`Password`,`EmailAddress`,`Pass1`,`User1` FROM users WHERE $user_cond");
        if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
            $email = $row['EmailAddress'];
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=2;login.php>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
?>
<h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>
    <form method="post" action="login.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
            <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: you forget to initialize the session at the top of your page.

Comment: Rather than expanding a user table to have X extra credentials, maybe you need a "subuser" table containing credentials? That way, upon successful authentication, the parent user ID gets put into the session. It has the benefit that you are not fixed on five credential sets too - you can have as many as you like.

Comment: (Aside: unsalted MD5 is no longer appropriate for password hashing, you'll need to fix that too).

Answer (score 0):

you must change you database design first. Try to understand what is 1:N relation. 
Now according to your problem you need 5 different user to login from same user id.

Now you have to create parent table which consist of ID and Email address.
Now create child table in which include foreign key of parent table and username password.

Now you can fire query on child table for username and password and you will be getting same ID for all 5 users.

Consider this **Hash your Password** and learn database normalisation. Then you can try implement your login.

Also check all the sessions.

Comment: Hash the password, not encrypt it.  Encrypted things can be de-crypted.  Passwords should be 1-way obscured so they can never be read.